# jTSS "There seems no TCS running"

Tags: java, tpm

I want to use jTSS on my Ubuntu 14.04 64bits, I have an hardware TPM in version 1.2.
I installed the .deb like said in the section 4.3 http://trustedjava.sourceforge.net/index.php?item=jtss/readme
I started the daemon : jtss (TCS running)

But if I want to run the tests in your packages (run_tests_simple.sh or run_test.sh) I have the error :
"Error! No TSP-TCS binding could be initialized. Both jTSS Wrapper and jTSS were tried. Check the TSP configuration file."

And with this command 'jtt tpm_version', I have the same error :

```
---------------------
IAIK Java TPM Tools
---------------------


16:34:56:631 [ERROR] TcTcsBindingSoap::connect (116):    There seems no TCS running
16:34:56:647 [ERROR] TcTcsBindingSoap::connect (116):    There seems no TCS running
iaik.tc.tss.api.exceptions.tsp.TcTspException:

TSS Error:
error layer:                0x3000 (TSP)
error code (without layer): 0x0103
error code (full):          0x3103a
error message: Core Service connection failed.

at iaik.tc.tss.impl.java.tsp.tcsbinding.soapservice.TcTcsBindingSoap.connect(TcTcsBindingSoap.java:117)
at iaik.tc.tss.impl.java.tsp.internal.TcTspInternal.TspContextConnect_Internal(TcTspInternal.java:368)
at iaik.tc.tss.impl.java.tsp.TcContext.connect(TcContext.java:174)
at iaik.tc.apps.jtt.tpm.TpmVersion.execute(TpmVersion.java:68)
at iaik.tc.utils.cmdline.SubCommand.run(SubCommand.java:69)
at iaik.tc.utils.cmdline.SubCommandParser.parse(SubCommandParser.java:41)
at iaik.tc.apps.JTpmTools.main(JTpmTools.java:224)
```

I removed trousers, but keep in /etc/group : tss:x:126:root,jtss

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your core service daemon was not started properly and isn't running. Have you seen this [message on Trustedjava-support mailinglist](http://sourceforge.net/p/trustedjava/mailman/message/33286913/)?

Since you are using Ubuntu 14.04, you will have a `jsvc` version >= 1.0.11

Try to add the line

```
-cwd "${ROOT}/soap" \
```

to the `jsvc` call in the `start()` function in `/etc/init.d/jtss`.

The call should look something like this after editing:

```
${JSVC_EXECUTABLE} -pidfile "${PIDFILE}" \
                   -cwd "${ROOT}/soap" \
                   -outfile "${LOGFILE}" \
                   -errfile '&1' \
                   -Djtss.tsp.ini.file="${LIBS}/ini/jtss_tsp.ini" \
                   -Djtss.tcs.ini.file="${LIBS}/ini/jtss_tcs.ini" \
                    ${USER:+-user "${USER}"} \
                   -wait ${TIMEOUT} \
                   -cp ${CLASSPATH_SOAP} ${EXECUTABLE}
```